# Magento percentage discount coupon codes not working after moving servers

Tags: magento, rackspace, discounts

Since moving our Magento store from Hostgator to Rackspace the percentage coupon codes are no longer applying the discount. When you enter a coupon code it says the coupon code was applied but no discount is given. Curiously, if you change it from a percentage discount to a fixed amount the discount is applied.

I have made no changes to these coupon codes. All I have done is move the website from Hostgator to Rackspace. I cannot, for the life of me, figure our why percentage coupon codes would be affected while others would not.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

install a cronjob to calll cron.php every 5 minutes!
Because the price of an active rule would be joined via sql...or call 'save and apply rule' from adminhtml

Comment: Would you update your answer with an explanation? That might refresh priceindexes for catalogrules but wouldn affect cartrules like in the question.

Comment: Yes, the percentage coupon codes are shopping cart price rules, not catalog rules. Not very familiar with cronjobs, will do some research and see if that is something that might fix this issue.